# How to enqueue scripts in WordPress from CDN?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to replicate a pen from codepen for which I have to load 3 script files from CDN and one from the server.

What is the correct syntax to load the scripts from CDN? [My codepen](http://codepen.io/karlovidek/pen/reemvP)

The script files are:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.2/TweenMax.min.js
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

In your `functions.php`, using [`wp_register_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/) and [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

**CSS**

```
wp_register_style( 'Font_Awesome', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_style('Font_Awesome');
```

**JS**

```
wp_register_script( 'jQuery', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js', null, null, true );
wp_enqueue_script('jQuery');
```

**Your case**

```
wp_register_script( 'jQuery', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js', null, null, true );
wp_enqueue_script('jQuery');
wp_register_script( 'TweenMax', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.2/TweenMax.min.js', null, null, true );
wp_enqueue_script('TweenMax');
wp_register_script( 'Slick', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.min.js', null, null, true );
wp_enqueue_script('Slick');
```

Answer (score -3):

```
function load_stylesheets()
{
    wp_register_style('style_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('style_css');

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts',  'load_stylesheets');
```

this is how you link a style.css through wp.  You put this in your "functions.php" file.  I don't know but from what I can see the previous person was correct in their suggestion but didn't include that you have to wrap the two in a function then create a webhook(the "add_action") and hook the aforementioned function by adding it to the callback parameter(callback hooks pretty much say "run this after you've run this").  I don't know if this will work but thought I should mention it.