# Did I enqueue my stylesheets incorrectly for my custom Wordpress theme?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, enqueue

I just built my first custom Wordpress theme from scratch using Bootstrap 3.4.0 (hooray!) however, my jumbotron section is not being responsive on my phone screen... I'm wondering if I enqueued something incorrectly?

Here's my stylesheets and scripts:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css"
  integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay"
  crossorigin="anonymous"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And here's my js.main doc:

````
 function custom_setup(){
     wp_enqueue_style ('google-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald');
     wp_enqueue_style ('google-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
     wp_enqueue_style ('fontawesome', '//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css'); 
     wp_enqueue_style ('boot', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
     wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri(), NULL, microtime(), all);
     wp_enqueue_script( 'boot1','https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js');
     wp_enqueue_scrit ('boot2', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
     wp_enqueue_script("main", get_theme_file_uri('/js/main.js'), NULL, microtime(), true); 

 }

 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_setup'); ```
````

Comment: You have a typo on this line: wp_enqueue_scrit ('boot2', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');

wp_enqueue_scrit should be wp_enqueue_script. However, since you're enqueue-ing a CSS file, it should be wp_enqueue_style. Maybe this could help solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40403364/how-to-enqueue-scripts-in-wordpress-from-cdn