# Leaflet Map on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, leaflet

So for past two hours I've been trying to figure out how to use Leaflet Map on my custom post type which I made... So problem is that I need map to show only on archive.php of that custom post type, not on the posts... And there seem to be no such plugin which will allow me to do that. What I've planned is that I will make 2 custom fields, one for longitude and another one for latitutde, and make map dynamic where users upon adding new campus will have to add coordinates which will be marked on archive.php page... This is how my functions.php looks:

```
function university_files() {

    wp_enqueue_script('custom.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('leaflet.js', 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('main-university-js', get_theme_file_uri('/js/scripts-bundled.js'),
    // microtime() is wordpress function which stops site from caching and forces it to load js again and again, and we don't use this on live server
    NULL, microtime(), true);
    
    

    wp_enqueue_style('custom-google-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i|Roboto:100,300,400,400i,700,700i');
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
    // microtime() forcing style.css to load everytime we refresh site and stops cahcing of the site
    wp_enqueue_style('university_main_styles', get_stylesheet_uri(), NULL, microtime());
    wp_enqueue_style('leaflet.css', 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('custom.css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css');

}
```

I've read documentation where I have to put designated div with id in my archive.php file and also I've edited CSS along with adding JS needed...

This is how my custom.css looks like:

```
#map {
  height: 180px;
}
```

custom.js:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
    .openPopup();
```

I have tried installing leaflet with NPM and enqueing it form node_modules but no luck... I don't know what I'm doing wrong here?
Also upon looking at my inspect elements console tab it shows this error message: "Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the script like:

```
wp_register_script('leaflet', 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js', null, null, true);
wp_enqueue_script('leaflet');
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40403412/8283938